# How to get compile time reference to current class instance

Tags: java, generics

I have a class member that is the type of my class, like a linked list:

```
class MyLinkedList {
    ...
    public MyLinkedList next;
    ...
}
```

When I extend this class

```
class MyExtendedLinkedList extends MyLinkedList{
    ...
    public doStuff(){
    ...
    }
}
```

I can't do something like

```
MyExtendedLinkedList myExLL = ...//Get some somewhere
myExLL.next.doStuff();
```

Since `next` doesn't return an instance of `MyExtendedLinkedList`. Obviously, this can be done with type casting but is there a compile time type safe way of declaring `next` so that I can get the derived type for all of my derived classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyLinkedList<T extends MyLinkedList<T>> {
  public T next;
}

class MyExtendedLinkedList extends MyLinkedList<MyExtendedLinkedList> {
  ...
}
```

Note, though, that you can't extend `MyExtendedLinkedList` and have this trick work; this only works if you extend directly from `MyLinkedList` and do the self-referential generics as above.

Comment: How can I adjust this if I do need to extend `MyExtendedLinkedList`?

Comment: You probably give up on type safety.  Seriously, that's really difficult to make work.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't understand what the difficulty could be. Could you please clarify?

Comment: It's somewhat tricky to explain other than "try it and see."  If `Foo extends Bar<T>`, then `SubFoo` is more or less restricted by the Java type system to still extend `Bar<T>`.  But here you have `Foo extends Bar<Foo>`, so `SubFoo` has to extend `Bar<Foo>` and can't extend `Bar<SubFoo>`.